# (OpenCV) Image segmentation where foreground and background are similar color?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

This image represents one of several thousand in a short video of a person writing information onto a whiteboard. The end goal of this program is to be able to create saved images of the whiteboard with the writer removed from the image. Common image segmentation and background subtraction practices work when the writers clothes are a distinct enough color, but it gets tricky when there is so much similarity between shirt and whiteboard.

I was curious as to whether or not anyone could point me in the direction of a solid algorithm.

Reference Image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A similar issues has been solved here : [OpenCV sharpen the edges (edges with no holes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284742/opencv-sharpen-the-edges-edges-with-no-holes)
@Nejc proposed a nice approach.
The same technique might be used.