# Image segmentation to obtain contours of all the five bowls

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I have tried several methods of image segmentation, while they're not working. 
I don't want to use Deep-learning method to solve this problem, **OpenCV-Python** is what I am currently learning.

Since considering the color of the background, the large white tray, is too similar with the foreground, especially the small white dishes, I have followed this link, aiming to get a satisfied segmentation result.
[OpenCV sharpen the edges (edges with no holes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42284742/opencv-sharpen-the-edges-edges-with-no-holes)
While the result is still disappointing......

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('2.jpg')
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
img_h, img_s, img_v = cv2.split(img_hsv)
img_s = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_s, (9, 9), 2, 2)
img_s = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img_s, 0.5, 0.5)
img_s = np.array(img_s, np.float32)
img_new_1 = cv2.Sobel(img_s, -1, 1, 0)
img_new_2 = cv2.Sobel(img_s, -1, 0, 1)
img_new_1 = cv2.multiply(img_new_1, img_new_1)
img_new_2 = cv2.multiply(img_new_2, img_new_2)
img_grad_abs_val_approx = cv2.pow((img_new_1 + img_new_2), 0.5)
filtered = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_grad_abs_val_approx, (9, 9), 2, 2)
mean, std = cv2.meanStdDev(filtered)
_, filtered_1 = cv2.threshold(filtered, mean[0] + std[0], 1.0, cv2.THRESH_TOZERO)
_, filtered_2 = cv2.threshold(filtered, mean[0] + std[0], 1.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
filtered_2 = np.array(filtered_2, np.uint8)

contour = cv2.findContours(filtered_2, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contour_img = np.zeros((filtered_2.shape[0], filtered_2.shape[1]), np.uint8)

cv2.drawContours(contour_img, contour[1], -1, 255)

cv2.imshow('image', filtered_1 / 50)
cv2.imshow('image_contour', contour_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dKO6.jpg)

I am totally confused about how to use traditional method(opencv) to solve this problem, the white dishes and the candies in them are so annoying.

Comment: The contrasted (colored) bowls are relatively easy (by binarization of the hue image). The white ones are intrinsically difficult, even "impossible". You might need a pre-stored bank of bowl shapes.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: @ZdaR The accurate contours of five bowls. The output instances is not provided to us